# How to receive all emails pertaining to a domain, on my production machine?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, forward, procmail

I have a strange requirement, any website user(not linux system user) will be getting a email id, say jack@mywebsite.com,sarah@mywebsite.com with which they are going to have a inbox feature built into their dashboard. Any outside user(can be anyone on the planet/not precisely my website user) can email this jack@mywebsite.com and jack receives email at her inbox(built into her dashboard). To accomplish this, I think, the following are the prerequisites:

1. I need to put MX records pointing to my production machine for mywebsite.com
2. I need to have a smtp server(can be Postfix) running on my prod machine

Along with these, do I need to setup any sort of mail accounts with MTA? I dont want create these website users as actual system users(I hat doing "useradd -s /sbin/nologin username
") How can I accomplish this entire behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sendmail this can be done via [virtusertable](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/features.html#virtusertable).
For postfix this is the [virtual alias table](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html).

So setup an MX record for the domain to point to your host with the postfix SMTP server setup.

Then config postfix to accept *@mywebsite.com and deliver it to a local mail box.
Details in the [Virtual Domain How To](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias)
Add the virtual domain (mywebsite.com) to the main.cf file, and then an entry for @mywebsite.com to point to a real account, say "webmail".

Then setup a real linux account for "webmail" and configure procmail in that account to process all incoming email and do whatever is necessary to put it into their web dashboard.

Comment: If you dont mind, Could you explain clearly? And I use postfix.

Comment: Just to be clear, any website user will be having their own personal login email id(say mypersonal_email@gmail.com) and he will be picking his own "mywebsite" ALIAS(equivalent of hisownusername@mywebsite.com) for his inbox. This will be his inbox email id. He receives everything at that email id.

Comment: Correct - this will send email for <anything>@mywebsite.com to webmail@mywebsite.com.  

Then setup webmail@mywebsite.com to do whatever you want with that incoming mail.  Ex, pump it all into "processmail.pl" - a perl script to put it wherever your webserver is going to be looking for email.

Comment: Ryan As you have mentioned,"...So setup an MX record for the domain to point to your host with the postfix SMTP server setup.", I did it. My mx record is pointing to www.mysite.com. Still I am unable to receive emails at my virtual alias account. My Postfix virtual file has: important@mysite.com web

Comment: I assume you ran postmap after updating the file?  'postmap /etc/postfix/virtual'?  Have you verified that the mx record is working and that mail is getting delivered to the machine, its just not being mapped to the virtual accnt?